# Retrieving original headers using Outlook Redemption

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-redemption

I'm working on a piece of Outlook automation that takes mail placed in a specific folder and exports it as an RFC822 formatted mail message. This output file will then be fed to the SpamAssassin tool sa-learn.exe.

```
For Each oItem In oFolder.Items
    If TypeOf oItem Is RDOMail Then
        Set oMailItem = oItem

        ' Deptermine the fully qualified path to save the file
        sFilePath = GetFilePath(oMailItem, "//Mailbox/SpamAssassin/Spam") 

        'Save the RFC822 format message
        oMailItem.SaveAs sFilePath, rdoSaveAsType.olRFC822

        DoEvents

        oMailItem.UnRead = False
        oMailItem.Delete
    End If
    DoEvents 'Let the Outlook UI thread breathe a bit
Next 'for each
```

Here are the message headers from a message saved using this code with redacted e-mail addresses.

```
From: "Swift Learning" <**********@***.*************.***>
To: <*****@********.***>
Subject: Foreign Languages are easily learned in this program
Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2012 10:11:38 -0700
Message-ID: <8518205138200566845@smx.jacksonpotts2.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_13AE_01CD6F0A.C9624870"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 14.0
Thread-Index: AQF4Lq/07oPqx1sKGPa5FKQSalUQXg==
```

What's missing from this are the relay headers that should look something like this.

```
Received: from [216.104.163.151] by mail.clarkzoo.org (ArGoSoft Mail Server .NET v.1.0.8.4) with ESMTP (EHLO smtp02-forward-1.daemonmail.net)
    for <*****@*********.***>; Tue, 31 Jul 2012 12:36:25 -0700
Received: from mxw03.daemonmail.net (unknown [216.104.161.13])
    by smtp02-forward-1.daemonmail.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 4447681FDB;
    Tue, 31 Jul 2012 12:18:01 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mxw03.daemonmail.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 748CF6A0DD
    for <***@******************.***>; Tue, 31 Jul 2012 12:17:52 -0700 (PDT)
```

How can I capture those relay headers?

**Update:**

Looking into this further, the raw headers as stored in the MailItem in Outlook are radically different from the RFC822 format as saved by Redemption.

Here's a side by side comparion.

Raw headers from the Properties dialog in Outlook.

```
Received: from [108.174.54.7] by mail.clarkzoo.org (ArGoSoft Mail Server .NET v.1.0.8.4) with ESMTP (EHLO upgraded.the-ameri-credit-review.com)
    for <*****@********.***>; Wed, 01 Aug 2012 07:34:15 -0700
Date: Wed, 1 Aug 2012 09:55:57 -0400
Subject: Your TransUnion, Equifax, and Experian Scores May Have Changed
From: "Credit Check" <info@the-ameri-credit-review.com>
To: <*****@********.***>
Message-ID: <132692318349a4a4158c108651c1428c@upgraded.the-ameri-credit-review.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Disposition: inline
SPF-Received: softfail
X-FromIP: 108.174.54.7
```

The headers from the RFC822 formatted file:

```
From: "Credit Check" <info@the-ameri-credit-review.com>
To: <*****@********.***>
Subject: Your TransUnion, Equifax, and Experian Scores May Have Changed
Date: Wed, 1 Aug 2012 06:55:57 -0700
Message-ID: <132692318349a4a4158c108651c1428c@upgraded.the-ameri-credit-review.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_011B_01CD6FC4.403990C0"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 14.0
Thread-Index: AQIRB+hjg86/OeRgMx9VYijSdeLwhw==
```

Those headers are only superficially the same.

- The relay headers are missing
- Date and Subjects are in different positions
- Date header has been be modified to repressent local time zone
- Content-Type has changed from "text/html; charset=us-ascii" to "multipart/alternative;"
- Headers have been added and headers have been removed

The better question is how does one capture the original headers of the message?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but try saving as rdoSaveAsType.olRFC822_Redemption instead of rdoSaveAsType.olRFC822. It seems to preserve all of the headers.